# joomla 2.5 media manager cannot upload image but no error

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, media-manager

i want to ask, that when i click start upload button in media manager, i got return a blank page, nothing error....
but when set debugging to development mode, i got some notice

```
Notice: Undefined index: CONTENT_LENGTH in /home/content/13/11749313/html/administrator/components/com_media/controllers/file.php on line 54

Notice: Undefined index: CONTENT_LENGTH in /home/content/13/11749313/html/administrator/components/com_media/controllers/file.php on line 55

Notice: Undefined index: CONTENT_LENGTH in /home/content/13/11749313/html/administrator/components/com_media/controllers/file.php on line 56

Notice: Undefined index: CONTENT_LENGTH in /home/content/13/11749313/html/administrator/components/com_media/controllers/file.php on line 57

Notice: Undefined index: name in /home/content/13/11749313/html/administrator/components/com_media/controllers/file.php on line 67

Notice: Undefined index: type in /home/content/13/11749313/html/administrator/components/com_media/controllers/file.php on line 67

Notice: Undefined index: tmp_name in /home/content/13/11749313/html/administrator/components/com_media/controllers/file.php on line 67

Notice: Undefined index: error in /home/content/13/11749313/html/administrator/components/com_media/controllers/file.php on line 67

Notice: Undefined index: size in /home/content/13/11749313/html/administrator/components/com_media/controllers/file.php on line 67
```

Please tell me what is wrong with media manager, its working fine till Friday, but from yesterday i am experiencing this problem...  I am using Joomla 2.5

Please help.

Comment: Are your **logs** and **tmp** settings in the *configuration.php* correct? What PHP version are you using? Are you running the latest version of Joomla 2.5? (**2.5.14**)

Answer (score 0):

Is the form name is same as name at /home/content/13/11749313/html/administrator/components/com_media/controllers/file.php?

I mean

```
<input type="file" name="file_abc" />
```

And same name param at file PHP.

```
$_FILES['file_abc'];
```

Comment: there is nothing like this in a file..as you mentioned.

Comment: If it's any shared hosting, they probably change some server config settings. Best way will be contact admin.

Comment: which admin, admin of server hosting... in my case "GoDaddy"?

Comment: @Retio - Where are you getting `$_FILES['file_abc'];` from?

Comment: @Lodder this was any example.

Comment: Godaddy people's showing no response.
They are saying that everything is fine from their side.